# Question put on hold due to bad editing, but has been updated since

Tags: support, on-hold

[I'm talking about this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37617821/richtextbox-wpf-c-sharp-cannot-insert-a-mathematical-under-root-value)

It has been put on hold, and I can see why, the original formatting was terrible and unclear what the user was asking. However, when I edited the question, I saw the user had done some bad edits and caused their images to not show. Now with the images in, the question makes a lot more sense and could be (possibly) answered. But the on-hold status was assigned just before my edit was approved.

So the question, should it still be on-hold now? The question quality has improved, though isn't fantastic still.

**[EDIT]**
I've undeleted the question as the question in question is still on hold.

Comment: Give it some time.  Your edit added it to the reopen queue.  People will see it and chose whether to reopen or not.

Comment: Ah, I did not know that, apologies. I'll delete this question then

Comment: I've reopened this question as the post is still on hold and I was hoping to get some reasoning why, is it just the bad formatting now, or is there another reason?

Comment: @Draken [A review](http://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/12572662) in the reopen queue was completed 2 days ago with the outcome 3x "Leave closed". So the community consensus (for now) is that its still off topic and should remain closed.

Comment: Unanimous as well, huh. All well, I guess it's up for the OP to ask again in a better method than before. I didn't think it quite be so swung in such a fashion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have given that question yet another edit so it now contains an answerable question. After consultation in the SOCVR room [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/34373211#34373211) the question was undeleted and re-opened.

The link you provided in a comment on that question might well be a good duplicate. I leave it to others to decide on that.